# Wrong field focussed after dialog closes

Tags: java, dialog, focus

I have an application where if a user action takes a certain amount of time, a dialog is shown that the interface is processing the action. Usually when the action is done, the dialog closes and the user can continue doing what he was doing before. This seems to work nearly always but every now and then the focus is moved from the component that was focused to the component that is 2 places after it in the focus chain.

I'm not able to create a small example program to show what is exactly happening but I have been able to debug the problem to a point where I'm hoping that someone could help me.

What seems to happen is this:

1. A sun.awt.TimedWindowEvent[WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS, {main window}...] event is processed by the dialog and passed on to the DefaultKeyboardFocusManager (DKFM) which will attempt to restoreFocus to the main window.
2. The DKFM tells the MostRecentFocusOwner to focus itself
3. The component registers itself as the MostRecentFocusOwner and tries to actually focus itself by calling peer.requestFocus.
4. *In WComponentPeer, the frame is focused but for some reason it returns false
5. The component sees it wasn't focused so it returns false as well
6. The DKFM sees that the component wasn't focused so it attempts to focus the next component
7. Step 3-5
8. Another focus event triggers, triggering step 1-7 again but because step 3 registers the new component as MostRecentFocusOwner the loop goes over the component from 6 and the next one from there
9. Another focus event triggers triggering the logic from step 1 but now step 4 returns true. The main window is shown and the wrong component is now focused.

For 4*: The thing that seems to be different in the situations where it works and where it doesn't is that the WComponentPeer checks after the focus request for the parentWindow where in the correct situations the parentWindow.isFocused() is true and in the failing situations the parentWindow.isFocused() will return false. The logging that is shown when I turn on the focus logging is "rejectFocusRequestHelper [...] Waiting for asynchronous processing of the request". 
This seems to indicate that the WComponentPeer knows about the possibility of having to handle focus requests asynchronously but the DKFM doesn't.

The relevant stacktrace is as follows:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.setMostRecentFocusOwner(Window, Component) line: 1814  
KeyboardFocusManager.setMostRecentFocusOwner(Component) line: 1801  
TheComponent(Component).requestFocusHelper(boolean, boolean, CausedFocusEvent$Cause) line: 7618 (3)
TheComponent(Component).requestFocusInWindow(CausedFocusEvent$Cause) line: 7533 
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.doRestoreFocus(Component, Component, boolean) line: 172 (6) 
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.restoreFocus(Window, Component, boolean) line: 151  (2)
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.restoreFocus(WindowEvent) line: 134 
DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent) line: 302   
ProgressDialog(Component).dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent) line: 4731 (1)
```

So my question is, am I looking at a Java bug here?

Also, the documentation mentions that you shouldn't assume that changing focus is done synchronously but it doesn't explain when it's synchronous and when it's not so what triggers the focus system in Java to handle certain focus requests asynchronously and others synchronously?

Edit: It could also be an event ordering thing.
While looking at the focusedWindow in KeyboardFocusManager in the correct situation it goes like this:

1. Main frame -> null
2. Null -> dialog
3. Focus change (I expect to dialog)
4. dialog -> null
5. null -> Main frame
6. Focus change (to lastFocussedComponent

In the failing situation it's like this:

1. Main frame -> null
2. 4x Focus change (to next focusable component on main frame)
3. null -> Main frame

It seems that the dialog is removed before it is actually shown. The event that clears the main frame as the active window is in both cases a WINDOW_FOCUS_LOST TimedWindowEvent with the dialog as opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell now it's caused by a Java bug. Because I noticed that the dialog never became focussed I was able to reproduce it in a small Java app:

```
public class TestFocusStuff extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  private final MyDialog mDialog = new MyDialog();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TestFocusStuff tfs = new TestFocusStuff();
    tfs.setVisible(true);
  }

  public TestFocusStuff()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
      c.add(tf);
      tf.addActionListener(this);
    }
    pack();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    mDialog.showQuickly();
  }

  private static class MyDialog extends JDialog
  {
    public void showQuickly()
    {
      setVisible(true);
      setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Pressing Enter in any of the textfields will popup the dialog and close it immediately. The focus will change as if Tab was pressed twice.

I expect that this should be fixed if I add a focuslistener and only close the dialog after I received that event.

Edit: I can now confirm that waiting for a WindowFocusEvent.windowGainedFocus before closing the dialog does help in preventing the bug.